# Showing the emulator

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, emulation

I want to learn and script Flutter and I installed the vscode and also extensions of Flutter. But I do not know the continuation of the process of installing such as showing the emulator and stuff.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: head over to https://flutter.dev/ there is a detailed guide for everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android setup, you need to install Android Studio and its plugins about Dart and Flutter, and for iOS setup, install Xcode too. And then you can start an emulator or a simulator. For more info, read the [official document](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos).

Comment: oops i did not mention:( I am using windows :)

Comment: ok, you need to install Android Studio too.  Then you can run the emulator.